# How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date and time?

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601, datetime-parsing, rfc3339

I need to parse [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) strings like `"2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686Z"` into Python's `datetime` type.

I have found [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) in the Python standard library, but it is not very convenient.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: related: [Convert timestamps with offset to datetime obj using strptime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12281975/4279)

Comment: To be clear: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is the main standard. [RFC 3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339) is a self-proclaimed “profile” of ISO 8601 that makes some [unwise overrides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC) of ISO 8601 rules.

Answer (score 678):

## `isoparse` function from *python-dateutil*

The [*python-dateutil*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) package has [`dateutil.parser.isoparse`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse) to parse not only RFC 3339 datetime strings like the one in the question, but also other [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date and time strings  that don't comply with RFC 3339 (such as ones with no UTC offset, or ones that represent only a date).

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.isoparse('2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686Z') # RFC 3339 format
datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 3, 20, 56, 35, 450686, tzinfo=tzutc())
>>> dateutil.parser.isoparse('2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686') # ISO 8601 extended format
datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 3, 20, 56, 35, 450686)
>>> dateutil.parser.isoparse('20080903T205635.450686') # ISO 8601 basic format
datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 3, 20, 56, 35, 450686)
>>> dateutil.parser.isoparse('20080903') # ISO 8601 basic format, date only
datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 3, 0, 0)
```

The *python-dateutil* package also has [`dateutil.parser.parse`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse). Compared with `isoparse`, it is presumably less strict, but both of them are quite forgiving and will attempt to interpret the string that you pass in. If you want to eliminate the possibility of any misreads, you need to use something stricter than either of these functions.

##### Comparison with Python 3.7+’s built-in [`datetime.datetime.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat)

`dateutil.parser.isoparse` is a full ISO-8601 format parser, but in Python ≤ 3.10 `fromisoformat` is deliberately *not*. In Python 3.11, `fromisoformat` supports almost all strings in valid ISO 8601. See `fromisoformat`'s docs for this cautionary caveat. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49784038/247696)).

Comment: For the lazy, it's installed via `python-dateutil` not `dateutil`, so: `pip install python-dateutil`.

Comment: Be warned that the `dateutil.parser` is intentionally hacky: it tries to guess the format and makes inevitable assumptions (customizable by hand only) in ambiguous cases. So ONLY use it if you need to parse input of unknown format and are okay to tolerate occasional misreads.

Comment: Agreed. An example is passing a "date" of 9999. This will return the same as datetime(9999, current month, current day). Not a valid date in my view.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev what package would you recommend for non-guessing parsing?

Comment: @bgusach `iso8601` [as another answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date/127934#127934).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev but that's for `iso8601` not `rfc3339`. Although the question is kind of confusing, seems to treat both as the same. I though we were talking only about the `rfc3339`

Comment: @bgusach [RFC 3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339), right in the abstract: _"This document defines a date and time format for use in Internet protocols that is a profile of the ISO 8601 standard for representation of dates and times using the Gregorian calendar."_

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I stand corrected then, thanks. I took a look at the doc, but did not understand that `a profile of the ISO 8601` means `a strict subset of ISO 8601` (I'm not a native speaker). BTW,  there seems to be an minor incompatibility between the both with the TZ `-00:00`, but I don't think that can cause any trouble in my case.

Comment: In Python 3, the parser always uses the `tzlocal` time zone, regardless of `Z` appearing at the end of the time string, on systems that are configured to use UTC as their default time zone. Numeric offsets produce a `tzoffset` tzinfo object.

Comment: For a shorter way to write it down you can do: `from dateutil.parser import parse as parsedate` and then use `parsedate()` instead of `dateutil.parser.parse()`

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev there's an update to the module that reads iso8601 dates: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse

Comment: It is a pity, you have to install a third party library for a very common use of a date format, i mean the notation ending with Z.

Comment: This should be fixed in Python 3.11

Comment: @noamcohen97 Thanks. I edited this answer and the other answer for Python 3.11

Answer (score 478):

Since Python 3.11, the standard library’s `datetime.fromisoformat` supports any valid ISO 8601 input. In earlier versions it only parses a specific subset, see the cautionary note in the docs. If you are using Python 3.10 or earlier on strings that don't fall into that subset (like in the question), see other answers for functions from outside the standard library. The docs:

> [*classmethod* **`datetime.fromisoformat(date_string)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat):
>
> Return a `datetime` corresponding to a *date_string* in any valid ISO 8601 format, with the following exceptions:
>
> 1. Time zone offsets may have fractional seconds.
> 2. The `T` separator may be replaced by any single unicode character.
> 3. Ordinal dates are not currently supported.
> 4. Fractional hours and minutes are not supported.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> >>> from datetime import datetime
> >>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04')
> datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 0)
> >>> datetime.fromisoformat('20111104')
> datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 0)
> >>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04T00:05:23')
> datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 5, 23)
> >>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04T00:05:23Z')
> datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 5, 23, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
> >>> datetime.fromisoformat('20111104T000523')
> datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 5, 23)
> >>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-W01-2T00:05:23.283')
> datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 4, 0, 5, 23, 283000)
> >>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04 00:05:23.283')
> datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 5, 23, 283000)
> >>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04 00:05:23.283+00:00')
> datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 5, 23, 283000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
> >>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04T00:05:23+04:00')   
> datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 5, 23, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=14400)))
> ```
>
> *New in version 3.7.*
>
> *Changed in version 3.11:* Previously, this method only supported formats that could be emitted by date.isoformat() or datetime.isoformat().

Comment: That's weird. Because a `datetime` may contain a `tzinfo`, and thus output a timezone, but `datetime.fromisoformat()` doesn't parse the tzinfo ? seems like a bug ..

Comment: Don't miss that note in the documentation, this doesn't accept *all* valid ISO 8601 strings, only ones generated by `isoformat`. It doesn't accept the example in the question `"2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686Z"` because of the trailing `Z`, but it does accept `"2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686"`.

Comment: To properly support the `Z` the input script can be modified with `date_string.replace("Z", "+00:00")`.

Comment: Note that for seconds it only handles either exactly 0, 3 or 6 decimal places. If the input data has 1, 2, 4, 5, 7 or more decimal places, parsing will fail!

Comment: As noted, this method will only successfully parse the output of `isoformat`, and is not fully ISO-8601 compliant, but very few languages are fully compliant given how large and arcane that standard is. Yes Java will accept timezones and date offsets, but anything further than that will fall over as well

Comment: @jox: Do you mean `"+0000"` instead of `"+00:00"`?  I am looking at the docs for `datetime.strptime()` and `%z` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: @kevinarpe no, `datetime.fromisoformat` seems to expect another format. I just tested both versions and while it works fine with `+00:00`, I get _"ValueError: Invalid isoformat string"_ with `+0000`.

Comment: @jox Great feedback.   So `datetime.fromisoformat` is even more insane that I thought!  How can Python be such a great language and ecosystem, but have such horrible date/time handling?  My Python date/time code is usually littered with "gotcha" comments and links to SO.com answers / comments!

Comment: `fromisoformat` accepts almost all ISO 8601 date strings in Python 3.11 now, so a lot of these comments are out of date.

Answer (score 235):

Note in Python 2.6+ and Py3K, the %f character catches microseconds.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

See issue [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue1158)

Comment: Note - if using Naive datetimes - I think you get no TZ at all - Z may not match anything.

Comment: in my case %f caught microseconds rather than Z, `datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')`  so this did the trick

Comment: Does Py3K mean Python 3000?!?

Comment: Fails if no ms or tz.

Comment: @Robino IIRC, "Python 3000" is an old name for what is now known as Python 3.

Comment: This answer (in its current, edited form) relies upon hard-coding a particular UTC offset (namely "Z", which means +00:00) into the format string. This is a bad idea because it will fail to parse any datetime with a different UTC offset and raise an exception. Also, even if you use this to parse a datetime with an offset of `Z`, you'll get back a "naive" `datetime` object with no timezone, instead of "timezone-aware" one with UTC as the timezone, which would be more correct.

Comment: fail for this string: 2008-09-03T20:56:35Z

Answer (score 196):

As of Python 3.7, you can *basically* (caveats below) get away with using [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse RFC 3339 datetimes, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def parse_rfc3339(datetime_str: str) -> datetime:
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(datetime_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
    except ValueError:
        # Perhaps the datetime has a whole number of seconds with no decimal
        # point. In that case, this will work:
        return datetime.strptime(datetime_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

It's a little awkward, since we need to try two different format strings in order to support both datetimes with a fractional number of seconds (like `2022-01-01T12:12:12.123Z`) and those without (like `2022-01-01T12:12:12Z`), both of which are valid under RFC 3339. But as long as we do that single fiddly bit of logic, this works.

Some caveats to note about this approach:

- It *technically* doesn't fully support RFC 3339, since RFC 3339 bizarrely lets you use a space instead of a `T` to separate the date from the time, even though RFC 3339 purports to be a profile of ISO 8601 and ISO 8601 does *not* allow this. If you want to support this silly quirk of RFC 3339, you could add `datetime_str = datetime_str.replace(' ', 'T')` to the start of the function.
- My implementation above is slightly more permissive than a strict RFC 3339 parser should be, since it will allow timezone offsets like `+0500` without a colon, which RFC 3339 does not support. If you don't merely want to parse known-to-be-RFC-3339 datetimes but also want to rigorously validate that the datetime you're getting is RFC 3339, use another approach or add in your own logic to validate the timezone offset format.
- This function definitely doesn't support all of *ISO 8601*, which includes a *much* wider array of formats than RFC 3339. (e.g. `2009-W01-1` is a valid ISO 8601 date.)
- It does *not* work in Python 3.6 or earlier, since in those old versions the `%z` specifier only matches timezones offsets like `+0500` or `-0430` or `+0000`, not RFC 3339 timezone offsets like `+05:00` or `-04:30` or `Z`.

Answer (score 85):

Try the [iso8601](https://pypi.org/project/iso8601/) module; it does exactly this.

There are several other options mentioned on the [WorkingWithTime](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WorkingWithTime) page on the python.org wiki.

Comment: Simple as `iso8601.parse_date("2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686Z")`

Comment: The question wasn't "how do I parse ISO 8601 dates", it was "how do I parse this exact date format."

Comment: @tiktak The OP asked "I need to parse strings like X" and my reply to that, having tried both libraries, is to use another one, because iso8601 has important issues still open. My involvement or lack thereof in such a project is completely unrelated to the answer.

Comment: [iso8601](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601/), a.k.a. *pyiso8601*, has been updated as recently as Feb 2014. The latest version supports a much broader set of ISO 8601 strings. I've been using to good effect in some of my projects.

Comment: Sadly that lib called "iso8601" on pypi is trivially incomplete. It clearly states it doesn't handle dates based on week numbers just to pick one example.

Comment: @Tobia: [iso8601](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601/0.1.11) seems to be getting updates again.

Answer (score 75):

### Python >= 3.11

[`fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat) now parses `Z` directly:

```py
from datetime import datetime

s = "2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686Z"

datetime.fromisoformat(s)
datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 3, 20, 56, 35, 450686, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

### Python 3.7 to 3.10

A simple option from one of the comments: replace `'Z'` with `'+00:00'` - and use `fromisoformat`:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = "2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686Z"

datetime.fromisoformat(s.replace('Z', '+00:00'))
# datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 3, 20, 56, 35, 450686, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

#### Why prefer `fromisoformat`?

Although `strptime`'s `%z` can parse the `'Z'` character to UTC, **`fromisoformat` is faster by ~ x40** (or even ~x60 for Python 3.11):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser

s = "2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686Z"

# Python 3.11+
%timeit datetime.fromisoformat(s)
85.1 ns ± 0.473 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)

# Python 3.7 to 3.10
%timeit datetime.fromisoformat(s.replace('Z', '+00:00'))
134 ns ± 0.522 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)

%timeit parser.isoparse(s)
4.09 µs ± 5.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

%timeit datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
5 µs ± 9.26 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

%timeit parser.parse(s)
28.5 µs ± 99.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

(Python 3.11.3 x64 on GNU/Linux)

See also: [A faster strptime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468126/a-faster-strptime)

Comment: @mikerodent: the point is that `fromisoformat` parses `+00:00` but not `Z` to [aware datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) with tzinfo being UTC. If your input e.g. ends with `Z+00:00`, you can just remove the `Z` before feeding it into `fromisoformat`. Other UTC offsets like e.g. `+05:30` will then be parsed to a static UTC offset (not an actual time zone).

Comment: Totally different point now (I understand a bit more about "awareness"). But I've noted in the docs "Changed in version 3.11: Previously, this method only supported formats that could be emitted by date.isoformat() or datetime.isoformat()." and "corresponding to a date_string in any valid ISO 8601 format". That might actually not be what one wants. The `fromisoformat` of `datetime.date` is more explicit: "Return a date corresponding to a date_string given in any valid ISO 8601 format... " ... and it gives some surprising examples of strings which work which are not simple YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 49):

Starting from Python 3.7, strptime supports colon delimiters in UTC offsets ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/32318930da70ff03320ec50813b843e7db6fbc2e)). So you can then use:

```
import datetime

def parse_date_string(date_string: str) -> datetime.datetime
    try:
       return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
    except ValueError:
       return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

EDIT:

As pointed out by Martijn, if you created the datetime object using isoformat(), you can simply use `datetime.fromisoformat()`.

EDIT 2:

As pointed out by Mark Amery, I added a try..except block to account for missing fractional seconds.

Comment: But in 3.7, you *also* have `datetime.fromisoformat()` which handles strings like your input automatically: `datetime.datetime.isoformat('2018-01-31T09:24:31.488670+00:00')`.

Comment: Good point. I agree, I recommend to use `datetime.fromisoformat()` and `datetime.isoformat()`

Comment: This is the only answer that actually meets the question criteria. If you have to use strptime this is the correct answer

Comment: You example fails on Python 3.6 with: `ValueError: time data '2018-01-31T09:24:31.488670+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'` that's due to `%z` not matching `+00:00`. However `+0000` matches `%z` see python doc https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: @Eric Yes, this answer only works in Python 3.7 or newer.

Comment: Alas, neither your `strptime` incantation nor `fromisoformat()` as @MartijnPieters suggests are sufficient to parse even all valid RFC 3339 datetimes (let alone ISO 8601, of course). Your `strptime` incantation chokes if given input without a fractional number of seconds (e.g. `'2018-01-31T09:24:31+00:00'`, while `fromisoformat` can't handle a timezone offset of `Z` (like used in the example in the question, or output from JavaScript's `Date.toISOString()` method).

Comment: @MarkAmery: You're right about the strptime limitation. I adjusted the answer for your edge case, thanks. Regarding fromisoformat: I would only use it if you created the date string with isoformat() also (as stated in the answer).

Comment: @MarkAmery: Python 3.11 has further improved `fromisoformat()` and it can handle the `Z` timezone now: `datetime.fromisoformat('2018-01-31T09:24:31Z')` produces `datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 31, 9, 24, 31, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`.

Answer (score 39):

What is the exact error you get? Is it like the following?

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2008-08-12T12:20:30.656234Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.Z")
ValueError: time data did not match format:  data=2008-08-12T12:20:30.656234Z  fmt=%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.Z
```

If yes, you can split your input string on ".", and then add the microseconds to the datetime you got.

Try this:

```
>>> def gt(dt_str):
        dt, _, us= dt_str.partition(".")
        dt= datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
        us= int(us.rstrip("Z"), 10)
        return dt + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=us)

>>> gt("2008-08-12T12:20:30.656234Z")
datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 12, 12, 20, 30, 656234)
```

Comment: You can't just strip .Z because it means timezone and can be different. I need to convert date to the UTC timezone.

Comment: A plain datetime object has no concept of timezone. If all your times are ending in "Z", all the datetimes you get are UTC (Zulu time).

Comment: if the timezone is anything other than `""` or `"Z"`, then it must be an offset in hours/minutes, which can be directly added to/subtracted from the datetime object.  you *could* create a tzinfo subclass to handle it, but that's probably not reccomended.

Comment: Additionally, "%f" is the microsecond specifier, so a (timezone-naive) strptime string looks like: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f" .

Comment: This will raise an exception if the given datetime string has a UTC offset other than "Z". It does not support the entire RFC 3339 format and is an inferior answer to others that handle UTC offsets properly.

Comment: Why not use the `%f` I don't get it ? I just saw this post because of it was used as a duplicate on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69953076/how-do-i-convert-type-of-a-datetime-string-which-has-z-in-it/69953133#69953133 but that seems not easy regarding juts use `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"`

Comment: Python 3.11 has a much improved `datetime.fromisoformat` which will handle most iso8601 and rfc3339 formats. https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat

Answer (score 27):

```py
import re
import datetime
s = "2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686Z"
d = datetime.datetime(*map(int, re.split(r'[^\d]', s)[:-1]))
```

Comment: I disagree, this is practically unreadable and as far as I can tell does not take into account the Zulu (Z) which makes this datetime naive even though time zone data was provided.

Comment: I find it quite readable. In fact, it's probably the easiest and most performing way to do the conversion without installing additional packages.

Comment: This is equivalent of d=datetime.datetime(*map(int, re.split('\D', s)[:-1])) i suppose.

Comment: def from_utc(date_str):
    """
    Convert UTC time data string to time.struct_time
    """
    UTC_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"
    return time.strptime(date_str, UTC_FORMAT)

Comment: a variation: `datetime.datetime(*map(int, re.findall('\d+', s))`

Comment: This results in a naive datetime object without timezone, right? So the UTC bit gets lost in translation?

Comment: @w00t: `aware_d = d.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)`

Comment: This has the benefit of working with incomplete iso strings including dates and second-less datetimes

Comment: **Not all formats of RFC3339 work with this code sample**, only if the second fraction part has 6 digits!
So the first example on [page 9 section 5.8 of RFC 3339 version July 2002](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.8) would not work:
 1985-04-12T23:20:50.52Z --> false: 1985-04-12T23:20:50.**0000**52
I mention this, because the question seems related to RFC3339 and only provides an 6 digit second fraction number as a 'like' _example_ not telling that all date times contain always 6 digits, or always trailing zeros in the second fraction part (...59.999000Z or ...59.999Z ?).

Comment: @BitLauncher  You saved my sanity!  I was trying all the combinations in this thread and you had the magic answer:  You can only have 6 decimals after the decimal point!!!  The timestamps I was working with had 9 decimals!  Who would think that should make a difference between conversion and invalid format?  I ended up using `fromisoformat(timestamp[:-4])` to keep it simple, and that worked fine!

Answer (score 22):

In these days, [Arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.org/) also can be used as a third-party solution:

```
>>> import arrow
>>> date = arrow.get("2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686Z")
>>> date.datetime
datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 3, 20, 56, 35, 450686, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Comment: Just use python-dateutil - arrow requires python-dateutil.

Answer (score 21):

Just use the `python-dateutil` module:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser as dp
>>> t = '1984-06-02T19:05:00.000Z'
>>> parsed_t = dp.parse(t)
>>> print(parsed_t)
datetime.datetime(1984, 6, 2, 19, 5, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

[Documentation](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: `dateutil.parser.parse` will accept formats that are definitely _not_ ISO 8601, like `"Sat Oct 11 17:13:46 UTC 2003"`. If you specifically want ISO 8601 parsing, you would probably rather use `dateutil.parse.isoparse` instead, as [Flimms's answer recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15228038/1709587).

Answer (score 16):

I have found [ciso8601](https://github.com/closeio/ciso8601) to be the fastest way to parse ISO 8601 timestamps.

It also has full support for RFC 3339, and a dedicated function for strict parsing RFC 3339 timestamps.

Example usage:

```
>>> import ciso8601
>>> ciso8601.parse_datetime('2014-01-09T21')
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 9, 21, 0)
>>> ciso8601.parse_datetime('2014-01-09T21:48:00.921000+05:30')
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 9, 21, 48, 0, 921000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=19800)))
>>> ciso8601.parse_rfc3339('2014-01-09T21:48:00.921000+05:30')
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 9, 21, 48, 0, 921000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=19800)))
```

The [GitHub Repo README](https://github.com/closeio/ciso8601/blob/f9f75de38450996e1ad699d966508a739e2bdfdc/README.rst) shows their speedup versus all of the other libraries listed in the other answers.

My personal project involved a lot of ISO 8601 parsing. It was nice to be able to just switch the call and go faster. :)

**Edit:** I have since become a maintainer of ciso8601. It's now faster than ever!

Comment: This looks like a great library!  For those wanting to optimize ISO8601 parsing on Google App Engine, sadly, we can't use it since it's a C library, but your benchmarks were insightful to show that native `datetime.strptime()` is the next fastest solution.  Thanks for putting all that info together!

Comment: @hamx0r, be aware that `datetime.strptime()` is not a full ISO 8601 parsing library. If you are on Python 3.7, you can use the `datetime.fromisoformat()` method, which is a little more flexible. You might be [interested in this more complete list of parsers](https://github.com/closeio/ciso8601/blob/benchmarking/README.rst#benchmark) which should be merged into the ciso8601 README soon.

Comment: ciso8601 works quite nice, but one have to first do "pip install pytz", because one cannot parse a timestamp with time zone information without the pytz dependency. Example would look like: dob = ciso8601.parse_datetime(result['dob']['date'])

Comment: @Dirk, [only in Python 2](https://github.com/closeio/ciso8601#dependency-on-pytz-python-2). But even that [should be removed](https://github.com/closeio/ciso8601/pull/58) in the next release.

Answer (score 13):

If you are working with Django, it provides the [dateparse module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.dateparse) that accepts a bunch of formats similar to ISO format, including the time zone.

If you are not using Django and you don't want to use one of the other libraries mentioned here, you could probably adapt [the Django source code for dateparse](https://github.com/django/django/blob/262d4db8c4c849b0fdd84550fb96472446cf90df/django/utils/dateparse.py#L84-L109) to your project.

Comment: Django's `DateTimeField` uses this when you set a string value.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to use dateutil, you can try this function:

```
def from_utc(utcTime,fmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"):
    """
    Convert UTC time string to time.struct_time
    """
    # change datetime.datetime to time, return time.struct_time type
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(utcTime, fmt)
```

Test:

```
from_utc("2007-03-04T21:08:12.123Z")
```

Result:

```
datetime.datetime(2007, 3, 4, 21, 8, 12, 123000)
```

Comment: This answer relies upon hard-coding a particular UTC offset (namely "Z", which means +00:00) into the format string passed to `strptime`. This is a bad idea because it will fail to parse any datetime with a different UTC offset and raise an exception. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30696682/1709587) that describes how parsing RFC 3339 with strptime is in fact impossible.

Comment: It's hard-coded but its sufficient for case when you need to parse zulu only.

Comment: @alexander yes - which may be the case if, for instance, you know that your date string was generated with JavaScript's [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method. But there's no mention of the limitation to Zulu time dates in this answer, nor did the question indicate that that's all that's needed, and just using `dateutil` is usually equally convenient and less narrow in what it can parse.

Answer (score 9):

I've coded up a parser for the ISO 8601 standard and put it on GitHub: https://github.com/boxed/iso8601. This implementation supports everything in the specification except for durations, intervals, periodic intervals, and dates outside the supported date range of Python's datetime module.

Tests are included! :P

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192), or if possible all of the above.

Answer (score 8):

This works for stdlib on Python 3.2 onwards (assuming all the timestamps are UTC):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").replace(
    tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(0)))
```

For example,

```
>>> datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(0)))
... datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 11, 6, 2, 47, 879129, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: This answer relies upon hard-coding a particular UTC offset (namely "Z", which means +00:00) into the format string passed to `strptime`. This is a bad idea because it will fail to parse any datetime with a different UTC offset and raise an exception. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30696682/1709587) that describes how parsing RFC 3339 with strptime is in fact impossible.

Comment: In theory, yes, this fails. In practice, I've never encountered an ISO 8601-formatted date that wasn't in Zulu time. For my very-occasional need, this works great and isn't reliant on some external library.

Comment: you could use `timezone.utc` instead of `timezone(timedelta(0))`. Also, the code works in Python 2.6+ (at least) if you [supply `utc` tzinfo object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2331635/4279)

Comment: Doesn't matter if you've encountered it, it doesn't match the spec.

Comment: You can use the `%Z` for timezone in the most recent versions of Python.

Answer (score 8):

I'm the author of iso8601utils. It can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/silverfernsys/iso8601utils) or on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601utils). Here's how you can parse your example:

```
>>> from iso8601utils import parsers
>>> parsers.datetime('2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686Z')
datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 3, 20, 56, 35, 450686)
```

Answer (score 7):

One straightforward way to convert an ISO 8601-like date string to a UNIX timestamp or `datetime.datetime` object in all supported Python versions without installing third-party modules is to use the [date parser of SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import with_statement, division, print_function
import sqlite3
import datetime

testtimes = [
    "2016-08-25T16:01:26.123456Z",
    "2016-08-25T16:01:29",
]
db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
c = db.cursor()
for timestring in testtimes:
    c.execute("SELECT strftime('%s', ?)", (timestring,))
    converted = c.fetchone()[0]
    print("%s is %s after epoch" % (timestring, converted))
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(converted))
    print("datetime is %s" % dt)
```

Output:

```
2016-08-25T16:01:26.123456Z is 1472140886 after epoch
datetime is 2016-08-25 12:01:26
2016-08-25T16:01:29 is 1472140889 after epoch
datetime is 2016-08-25 12:01:29
```

Comment: Thanks. This is disgusting. I love it.

Comment: What an incredible, awesome, beautiful hack! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Bad and the Ugly section.

Comment: Note that SQLite's date & time parsing is both more permissive than RFC 3339 and not permissive enough to handle all of ISO 8601, so it's not a perfect approach to parsing either format. Also, this is a hideous hack. But I suppose the fact that it avoids the need to install third party libraries is a virtue of sorts!

Answer (score 7):

Django's [`parse_datetime()`](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/utils.html#django.utils.dateparse.parse_datetime) function supports dates with UTC offsets:

```
parse_datetime('2016-08-09T15:12:03.65478Z') =
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 9, 15, 12, 3, 654780, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

So it could be used for parsing ISO 8601 dates in fields within entire project:

```
from django.utils import formats
from django.forms.fields import DateTimeField
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime

class DateTimeFieldFixed(DateTimeField):
    def strptime(self, value, format):
        if format == 'iso-8601':
            return parse_datetime(value)
        return super().strptime(value, format)

DateTimeField.strptime = DateTimeFieldFixed.strptime
formats.ISO_INPUT_FORMATS['DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS'].insert(0, 'iso-8601')
```

Answer (score 7):

An another way is to use specialized parser for ISO-8601 is to use [*isoparse*](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse) function of dateutil parser:

```
from dateutil import parser

date = parser.isoparse("2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686+01:00")
print(date)
```

Output:

```
2008-09-03 20:56:35.450686+01:00
```

This function is also mentioned in the [documentation for the standard Python function *datetime.fromisoformat*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat):

> A more full-featured ISO 8601 parser, dateutil.parser.isoparse is
>   available in the third-party package dateutil.

Answer (score 5):

If [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html) is used anyway, I can recommend [`Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) from `pandas`. There you can

```
ts_1 = pd.Timestamp('2020-02-18T04:27:58.000Z')    
ts_2 = pd.Timestamp('2020-02-18T04:27:58.000')
```

Rant: It is just unbelievable that we still need to worry about things like date string parsing in 2021.

Comment: pandas is **strongly** discouraged for this simple case: It depends on pytz, which violates the python standard, and pd.Timestamp is subtly not a compatible datetime object.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you have some pointers for me? I was not able to find pytz: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7036de35378d9db6236de2d70fe5f104b0bcdc9c/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyi#L31 and I’m not sure what Python standard and its violation you are referring to.

Comment: See the [rant by Paul Ganssle](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/37654).
As for incompatibility, execute both `datetime.fromisoformat('2021-01-01T00:00:00+01:00').tzinfo.utc` and `pandas.Timestamp('2021-01-01T00:00:00+01:00').tzinfo.utc` : Not the same at all.

Comment: Thank you for pointers to this ongoing work. I didn’t know about that issue, but I really hope they fix it soon! But again: I can’t believe that time parsing is still an issue. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Because ISO 8601 allows many variations of optional colons and dashes being present, basically `CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm]`. If you want to use strptime, you need to strip out those variations first.

**The goal is to generate a utc datetime object.**

---

If you just want a basic case that work for UTC with the Z suffix like `2016-06-29T19:36:29.3453Z`:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp.translate(None, ':-'), "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S.%fZ")
```

---

If you want to handle timezone offsets like `2016-06-29T19:36:29.3453-0400` or `2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686+05:00` use the following. These will convert all variations into something without variable delimiters like  `20080903T205635.450686+0500` making it more consistent/easier to parse.

```
import re
# this regex removes all colons and all 
# dashes EXCEPT for the dash indicating + or - utc offset for the timezone
conformed_timestamp = re.sub(r"[:]|([-](?!((\d{2}[:]\d{2})|(\d{4}))$))", '', timestamp)
datetime.datetime.strptime(conformed_timestamp, "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S.%f%z" )
```

---

If your system does not support the `%z` strptime directive (you see something like `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S.%f%z'`) then you need to manually offset the time from `Z` (UTC). Note `%z` may not work on your system in python versions < 3 as it depended on the c library support which varies across system/python build type (i.e. Jython, Cython, etc.).

```
import re
import datetime

# this regex removes all colons and all 
# dashes EXCEPT for the dash indicating + or - utc offset for the timezone
conformed_timestamp = re.sub(r"[:]|([-](?!((\d{2}[:]\d{2})|(\d{4}))$))", '', timestamp)

# split on the offset to remove it. use a capture group to keep the delimiter
split_timestamp = re.split(r"[+|-]",conformed_timestamp)
main_timestamp = split_timestamp[0]
if len(split_timestamp) == 3:
    sign = split_timestamp[1]
    offset = split_timestamp[2]
else:
    sign = None
    offset = None

# generate the datetime object without the offset at UTC time
output_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(main_timestamp +"Z", "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S.%fZ" )
if offset:
    # create timedelta based on offset
    offset_delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(sign+offset[:-2]), minutes=int(sign+offset[-2:]))
    # offset datetime with timedelta
    output_datetime = output_datetime + offset_delta
```

Comment: This is broken; some quick experimentation shows it raises an exception if `timestamp` is `'2016-06-29T19:36:29.123Z'` or `'2016-06-29T19:36:29+00:00'`, both of which are valid RFC 3339 and ISO 8601 datetimes.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays there's [Maya: Datetimes for Humans™](https://github.com/kennethreitz/maya), from the author of the popular Requests: HTTP for Humans™ package:

```
>>> import maya
>>> str = '2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686Z'
>>> maya.MayaDT.from_rfc3339(str).datetime()
datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 3, 20, 56, 35, 450686, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Answer (score 3):

### `datetime.fromisoformat()` is improved in Python 3.11 to parse most ISO 8601 formats

[datetime.fromisoformat()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) can now be used to parse most ISO 8601 formats, barring only those that support fractional hours and minutes. Previously, this method only supported formats that could be emitted by datetime.isoformat().

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04T00:05:23Z')
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 5, 23, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('20111104T000523')
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 5, 23)
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2011-W01-2T00:05:23.283')
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 4, 0, 5, 23, 283000)
```

Comment: An excellent improvement to the previous situation. This should be most people's first choice.

Answer (score 2):

The python-dateutil will throw an exception if parsing invalid date strings, so you may want to catch the exception.

```
from dateutil import parser
ds = '2012-60-31'
try:
  dt = parser.parse(ds)
except ValueError, e:
  print '"%s" is an invalid date' % ds
```

Comment: I think it will throw an exception sometimes, it is not guaranteed to throw an exception if it can make a best effort at guessing what the datetime is.

Comment: Error hiding is in top three of anti-patterns: Don't.

Answer (score 1):

For something that works with the 2.X standard library try:

```
calendar.timegm(time.strptime(date.split(".")[0]+"UTC", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z"))
```

calendar.timegm is the missing gm version of time.mktime.

Comment: This just ignores the timezone '2013-01-28T14:01:01.335612-08:00' --> parsed as UTC, not PDT

Comment: Besides ignoring the timezone as @gatoatigrado notes, this also raises an exception if you give it input which has a timezone but _not_ a fractional number of seconds (and thus no `.` character), like `2022-10-09T15:49:22-07:00`. Such a value is a valid RFC 3339 and ISO 8601 date time string, so a parser shouldn't choke on it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to great [Mark Amery's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30696682/719457) I devised function to account for all possible ISO formats of datetime:

```
class FixedOffset(tzinfo):
    """Fixed offset in minutes: `time = utc_time + utc_offset`."""
    def __init__(self, offset):
        self.__offset = timedelta(minutes=offset)
        hours, minutes = divmod(offset, 60)
        #NOTE: the last part is to remind about deprecated POSIX GMT+h timezones
        #  that have the opposite sign in the name;
        #  the corresponding numeric value is not used e.g., no minutes
        self.__name = '<%+03d%02d>%+d' % (hours, minutes, -hours)
    def utcoffset(self, dt=None):
        return self.__offset
    def tzname(self, dt=None):
        return self.__name
    def dst(self, dt=None):
        return timedelta(0)
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'FixedOffset(%d)' % (self.utcoffset().total_seconds() / 60)
    def __getinitargs__(self):
        return (self.__offset.total_seconds()/60,)

def parse_isoformat_datetime(isodatetime):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(isodatetime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(isodatetime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    except ValueError:
        pass
    pat = r'(.*?[+-]\d{2}):(\d{2})'
    temp = re.sub(pat, r'\1\2', isodatetime)
    naive_date_str = temp[:-5]
    offset_str = temp[-5:]
    naive_dt = datetime.strptime(naive_date_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
    offset = int(offset_str[-4:-2])*60 + int(offset_str[-2:])
    if offset_str[0] == "-":
        offset = -offset
    return naive_dt.replace(tzinfo=FixedOffset(offset))
```

Answer (score -1):

Initially I tried with:

```python
from operator import neg, pos
from time import strptime, mktime
from datetime import datetime, tzinfo, timedelta

class MyUTCOffsetTimezone(tzinfo):
    @staticmethod
    def with_offset(offset_no_signal, signal):  # type: (str, str) -> MyUTCOffsetTimezone
        return MyUTCOffsetTimezone((pos if signal == '+' else neg)(
            (datetime.strptime(offset_no_signal, '%H:%M') - datetime(1900, 1, 1))
          .total_seconds()))

    def __init__(self, offset, name=None):
        self.offset = timedelta(seconds=offset)
        self.name = name or self.__class__.__name__

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return self.offset

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return self.name

    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)


def to_datetime_tz(dt):  # type: (str) -> datetime
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'
    if dt[-6] in frozenset(('+', '-')):
        dt, sign, offset = strptime(dt[:-6], fmt), dt[-6], dt[-5:]
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(dt),
                                      tz=MyUTCOffsetTimezone.with_offset(offset, sign))
    elif dt[-1] == 'Z':
        return datetime.strptime(dt, fmt + 'Z')
    return datetime.strptime(dt, fmt)
```

But that didn't work on negative timezones. This however I got working fine, in Python 3.7.3:

```python
from datetime import datetime


def to_datetime_tz(dt):  # type: (str) -> datetime
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'
    if dt[-6] in frozenset(('+', '-')):
        return datetime.strptime(dt, fmt + '%z')
    elif dt[-1] == 'Z':
        return datetime.strptime(dt, fmt + 'Z')
    return datetime.strptime(dt, fmt)
```

Some tests, note that the out only differs by precision of microseconds. Got to 6 digits of precision on my machine, but YMMV:

```python
for dt_in, dt_out in (
        ('2019-03-11T08:00:00.000Z', '2019-03-11T08:00:00'),
        ('2019-03-11T08:00:00.000+11:00', '2019-03-11T08:00:00+11:00'),
        ('2019-03-11T08:00:00.000-11:00', '2019-03-11T08:00:00-11:00')
    ):
    isoformat = to_datetime_tz(dt_in).isoformat()
    assert isoformat == dt_out, '{} != {}'.format(isoformat, dt_out)
```

Comment: May I ask why did you do `frozenset(('+', '-'))`? Shouldn't a normal tuple like `('+', '-')` be able to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Sure, but isn't that a linear scan rather than a perfectly hashed lookup?

Comment: At least a couple of bugs in your `to_datetime_tz` function: 1. datetime strings without a decimal point in the seconds (like `2019-03-11T08:00:00+11:00`) trigger exceptions despite being valid ISO 8601 and RFC 3339 datetimes, and 2. timezone offset `Z` is treated differently from `+00:00` even though they are supposed to mean the same thing.

Comment: As for @PrahladYeri's point about the frozenset, Prahlad is quite right. There's no way the `frozenset` lookup is gonna be faster with only two items, especially when you're actually having to construct and iterate over an equivalent 2-item tuple anyway as part of the construction of the `frozenset`. And even if it were faster, the cost of doing a lookup in a 2-item collection is never gonna matter.

Comment: I suppose you can do length checks on the input string to determine what's in it. You're welcome to edit this answer from > 3 years ago.